# How can I store the video blob-Data on server with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video, video-recording, web-storage

I want to save the data from a recorded video on server by php and ajax using the script of [Media stream recorder from Mido](https://github.com/Mido22/MediaRecorder-sample) as basic. Only work for audio data, not for video files. The video files are without picture, only audio.
The storage of the video and playing by Midos Javascript works fine. Only my script for saving the file on the server is not quite complete or wrong.

I use this data for the preparation:

```
let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
, url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
, li = document.createElement('li')
, mt = document.createElement(media.tag)
, hf = document.createElement('a')
;
```

and want to send this by this script:

```
  var data     = new FormData();
  data.append('file', blob);
  data.append('sessID', sessID);
  data.append('idx', idx);

  $.ajax({
    url :  "./srv/lb/recorder/postWave.inc.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('data: '+data);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Fehler.");
    }
  });
```

That is the whole function in Javascript:

```
function makeLink() {
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
    , url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    , li = document.createElement('li')
    , mt = document.createElement(media.tag)
    , hf = document.createElement('a')
  ;
  console.log('url: '+url+'//');
  mt.controls = true;
  mt.src = url;
  hf.href = url;
  hf.download = `${counter++}${media.ext}`;
//  hf.innerHTML = `download ${hf.download}`;
  li.appendChild(mt);
//  li.appendChild(hf);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  $('#btnWeiter').css({'visibility':'visible'});
  $('.btn').remove();

//      var filename = 'test.wav';
      var data     = new FormData();
      data.append('file', blob);
      data.append('sessID', sessID);
      data.append('idx', idx);

      $.ajax({
        url :  "./srv/lb/recorder/postWave.inc.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('data: '+data);
        },
        error: function() {
          alert("Fehler.");
        }
      });
}
```

and that is my php-code:

```
$ext = $_POST['idx'] == 1 ? '.ogg' : '.mp4';

if(isset($_FILES['file']) and !$_FILES['file']['error']) {
  $fname = "audio_" . $_POST['sessID'] . $ext;

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "../../data/wav/" . $fname);
}
```

It works fine with *.ogg files, but the *.mp4 files are only with audio.

Maybe I have more to do for video files?

Comment: Audio data of a video doesn’t randomly get lost. You are not doing _any_ “video processing” on the server side here, this is just storing the file you uploaded as is. If after this upload you have a video with no audio - then you had a video with no audio _before_ you uploaded it already.

Comment: I have a file in every case with audio. I have no problems with audio. The *.mp4 file have only something to hear not to see. What I have to do for 'video processing' in your opinion?

Comment: No clue what your actual problem is now. At first it sounded like you were uploading videos that contained audio, but then the audio was somehow lost. If that is not it - then please explain what the actual problem is, properly.

Comment: I want to save a recorded video ([media recorder](https://github.com/Mido22/MediaRecorder-sample) ) on the server by PHP and Ajax using the script of Media stream recorder from Mido as a base. That means I save audio files and video files. But I get only audio in both cases. Is that better to understand now?

Comment: strictly speaking:
I want to save the video file correctly and completely on the server.
Unfortunately, this does not work yet. That is the absolute only problem. Does anyone have a useful hint for me?